# Application of Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The problem requests to use Fourier transformation, which I totally have no clue how.
It states as following:

> $u\in C^2_0$, prove $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}u_{xx}u_{yy}-u_{xy}^2 \,dx = 0$$

Any comments would be welcome.
Cheers.

------update-------

One can show 
$$-\xi^i \xi^j \mathcal{F}(u)(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}e^{-i\xi x}u_{x^i x^j}(x)\, dx$$.

Compose the LHS by the above equation, it shows the result is zero.
But I still have the term $e^{-i\xi x}$, should I take $\xi = 0$?

Comment: Taking $\xi=0$ won't help because the integrand in the desired claim involves a *product* of double partial derivatives, not just $u$. Also, it'd make more sense to write $\mathcal{F}(u)(\xi)$ rather than $\mathcal{F}(u(\xi))$ in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Plancherel's theorem twice, once on $\iint_{{\mathbb R}^2} u_{xx} u_{yy}$ and
once on $\iint_{{\mathbb R}^2} u_{xy}^2$

Comment: Could you be more precise on how to work out the integral equations?

Comment: $$ \int_{{\mathbb R}^2} \overline{u} v =  \int_{{\mathbb R}^2} \overline{{\cal F} u} \ {\cal F} v$$

Comment: What do you mean the bar $\bar{u}$?

Comment: Complex conjugate